Is there an option to remove dimension name in front of column name
I'm using import data from the Analysis Services to excel . Is there an option to not show the dimension in front of the column name on my tabular table?
I will try search in properties of dimension but i dont find any option  how visible name

Yes.  Open the Power Query editor and new Analysis Services source.  Then paste in a custom DAX query that renames the columns to whatever you like.  EG
evaluate SELECTCOLUMNS(Customer, "Customer ID", Customer[Customer Id], "First Name", Customer[First Name], ...)

